# (PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist) while fetching data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have object `A` which has a set of object `B`

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
           fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
           mappedBy = "a")
private Set<B> b = new HashSet<>();
```

and in object `B`

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
@JsonBackReference
private A a;
```

I know somehow we can have **bidirectional consistency** problem with wrong annotations while **"persisting"** data...

I have no problem with saving here:

- creating object A
- creating object B
- adding A to B
- adding B as a list to A
- saving A

I have a DAO class for object B which extends `JpaRepository` even if I forget about my custom methods and call `findALl` from `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`

I get this exception!

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.myproject.model.B; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.myproject.model.B
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:280)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke
```

why this is happening while fetching data?

**my unit test method:**

```
@Test
void test(){
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    b.setA(a);
    a.setB(Collections.singleton(b));
    
    aDao.save(a); //works fine
    
    specificService();
}
```

**and my service method:**
where the exception happens when I call `bDao.findAll()`

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@Override
public void specificService(){
    A a = aDao.findAll(); //works fine I can see b in a
    B b = bDao.findAll(); //PersistentObjectException
}
```

I have this in my config test...

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

Comment: Could you provide a piece of code which causes the exception?

Comment: I just updated my question but I'm just calling findAll() method from JoaRepository nothing else! @jwpol

Comment: Possibly (or even probably) because there are buffered updates which Hibernate will flush to ensure consistent results from the query. But if you don't add the relevant code then no one can help you.

Comment: hi @AlanHay I tried to explain what I did more, thanks for checking

Comment: Could you please provide the whole stacktrace? You have just copied the excpetion. Can you spot what(which line of your code) caused it?

Comment: The problem is as noted above however without the full context no further info can be given. I would also avoid using this property: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true

Comment: hi @EiriniGraonidou I just put stacktrace, thanks for checking.

Comment: do you think that config is the problem? but I need that for fetching child (B) from A for my test cases @AlanHay